# как считать из файла количество элементов определенного типа?

Tags: c++, fstream

Задание: дан файл с некоторым количеством предложений, вывести на экран то предложение в котором большее количество цифр, вижу алгоритм следующим образом: нужно сначала посчитать в файле кол-во разделяющих знаков предложения(точка, воскл знак, знак вопроса, многоточие) и далее каким-то образом через цикл for посчитать кол-во цифр в каждом из них, но сейчас понять с малого, для этого необходимо посчитать просто кол-во цифр в файле)
Пытаюсь сделать следующим образом: хочу загнать все элементы к double типу, но ничего не выходит, предполагаю что нужно делать как-то через метод get(), потому что нам нужны числа, а не цифры, но как-то не понимаю(

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    const string wayToFile = " " ;
    int  count = 0;
    double a;

    ifstream file;
    file.open(wayToFile);
    while (!file.eof()) {
        file.get();
        if (file >> a){
        count += 1;

}

    }
}
```

Comment: get метод и isdigit() функция. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/isdigit/ . А вот get http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/get/ .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
vector<string>  vs;    
copy(istream_iterator<string>(file), istream_iterator<string>(),  back_inserter(vs));
string space(".?!");
```

теперь у вас в векторе  все слова из файла. сравните последный символ с символами из `space`, в этой части посчитайте количество цифр, и так для каждой части вектора. Как все делать и как хранить результаты и сравнивать, а потом выводить, не думаю, что вы не сможете